# How to fill progress bar based on number of letters typed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to make an input box that has a div on the bottom which will act sort of a progress bar to tell you when you have enough characters typed.

I can't get this animation to work, even though I thought it would be a lot easier when I decided to try this project.

Please let me know what is wrong with my code. Thanks!

```
<div id='cntnr'>
  <div id='inptDiv'>
    <input id='inpt1'>
    <div id='prgInd'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
var main = function() {
  var inptAmnt = document.getElementById('inpt1').value;
  if(inptAmnt.length === 1) {
    $('#prgInd').css('width', 25);
  }
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

I also tried this code first but it didn't work either:

```
var main = function() {
  var inptAmnt = document.getElementById('inpt1').value;
  if(inptAmnt.length === 1) {
    $('#prgInd').animate({
      width:25
    },200 )
  }
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qcsb53ha/

Comment: Did you add jQuery to your fiddle?

Comment: Yes and I wasn't editing my code on fiddle I was editing it on CodePen where I have it in too. Good thinking tho, wouldn't have been the first time I did that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery to listen to the `change`, `keyup` and `paste` events of your text `input`.

Then, work out a percentage, based on your desired input length; and use this percentage to set the `width` of the progress bar.

If the "percentage" is above 100 - just reset it to 100 again. jQuery code is below:

```
var desiredLength = 4; // no jokes please...

// Listen to the change, keyup & paste events.
$('#text-box').on('change keyup paste', function() {
    // Figure out the length of the input value
    var textLength = $('#text-box').val().length;

    // Calculate the percentage
    var percent = (textLength / desiredLength) * 100;
    // Limit the percentage to 100.
    if (percent > 100) {
      percent = 100;
    }

    // Animate the width of the bar based on the percentage.
    $('.progress-bar').animate({
      width: percent + '%'
    }, 200)
});
```

---

See the working JSFiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/jqbka5j8/1/

I've included normal code for setting the width, and the code for animating the width. You can comment/uncomment the necessary ones and test appropriately.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seems complicated but it will work. Do you know what I did wrong in my other code, so I don't make the mistake in the future?

Comment: Thanks! :) It's fairly easy once you've looked at how it works a few times (the percentage bit is just simple maths, in all fairness). In regards to your original code, you weren't listening to any events. So the code was only running once (on page load), and never again. And with the textbox loading with no value, the `if` block was never stepped into. FYI: the `$("selector").on("event", function() { ... });` wires up a handler to the element, for the named event, in jQuery. The `function() { ... }` is what then executes. See https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-handler-attachment/

Comment: Alright thanks for the help! I'm going to go through those event handlers to use them for efficiently in the future.

Comment: No worries. In no time at all you'll be using them all over your code like there's no tomorrow. Don't forget to upvote/accept if this answer is helpful/what you used to solve your problem :) Happy coding!

Comment: Just as an extra note: I would advise to consider between using the non/animated version of setting the width (as per the fiddle). Each animation waits for the previous to finish. If you type fast enough, it can stack up the animations in a backlog. Just try typing a letter and then backspace repeatedly, very quickly - you'll see what I mean

Answer (score 1):

**There's no need the use of javascript, you can use only pure CSS and [Content Editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content):**

HTML

```
<div>
    <span contenteditable="true">sdfsd</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
span 
{
    border: solid 1px black;
}
div 
{
    max-width: 200px;   
}
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YZPmC/813/)

Comment: Hi @Yuri, how does this address the OP's question about the progress bar?